# Problem with Jackson ArrayNode.add Java function

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a function that should change some values on Object that have some objects of array.

This Object is:

```
{"avg":{"00:00":[],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"avg_hum":{"00:00":[],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"max":{"00:00":[],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"min":{"00:00":[],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"max_hum":{"00:00":[],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"min_hum":{"00:00":[],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"beginDate":"","endDate":""}
```

And I need to add values to arrays (like: {"00:00": [25],...})

So, I tried something like ("data_raw" is the received object):

```
ArrayNode array = mapper.createArrayNode();

array = (ArrayNode) data_raw.get("avg").get("00:00");

array.add((double) 25.11666711171468);

System.out.println("data_raw: " + data_raw.toString());
```

And the result ("data_raw" object) is:

```
data_raw: {"avg":{"00:00":[25.11666711171468],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"avg_hum":{"00:00":[25.11666711171468],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"max":{"00:00":[25.11666711171468],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"min":{"00:00":[25.11666711171468],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"max_hum":{"00:00":[25.11666711171468],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"min_hum":{"00:00":[25.11666711171468],"01:00":[],"02:00":[],"03:00":[],"04:00":[],"05:00":[],"06:00":[],"07:00":[],"08:00":[],"09:00":[],"10:00":[],"11:00":[],"12:00":[],"13:00":[],"14:00":[],"15:00":[],"16:00":[],"17:00":[],"18:00":[],"19:00":[],"20:00":[],"21:00":[],"22:00":[],"23:00":[]},"beginDate":"","endDate":""}
```

I expect that just "avg":{"00:00":[X],...} be changed, but all objects with "00:00" name are being replaced regardless of the selected "primary field": "avg".

Can someone help me?

EDIT:

Complete related code:

```
String[] name_db_data = {"avg", "avg_hum", "max", "min", "max_hum", "min_hum"};
SimpleDateFormat hourFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
reType = reportType.detailedDailyReport;
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query); // The String "query" is a dynamic MySQL query.

while(rs.next())
            {
                if(reType == reportType.detailedDailyReport)
                {
                    int count4 = 0;

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.setTime(rs.getTime("hour"));

                    for(count4 = 0; count4 < name_db_data.length; count4 ++)
                    {
                        ArrayNode array_aux2 = mapper.createArrayNode();
                        array_aux2 = (ArrayNode) data_raw.get(name_db_data[count4]).get(hourFormatted.format(c.getTime()));
                        array_aux2.add(rs.getDouble(name_db_data[count4]));
                    }

                }
```

Comment: can you show more code

Comment: @Deadpool Yes...

The related code are into a for loop:


`for(count = 0; count < name_fields.length; count++)`
`{`

`ArrayNode array = mapper.createArrayNode();`

`array = (ArrayNode) data_raw.get(name_fields[count]).get("00:00");`

`array.add((double) 25.11666711171468);`

`System.out.println("data_raw: " + data_raw.toString());`

`}`

Comment: You don't need that code in for loop, just remove the for loop @LeonardoAugustoCorintaTrint

Comment: But I have different field names ("name_fields" string vector) to set values... I not understand how `array.add((double) 25.11666711171468);` can add this value to different objects on data_raw.

Comment: @Deadpool With or without for loop, the problem continues...

Comment: Please add the complete code in post @LeonardoAugustoCorintaTrint

Comment: @Deadpool the post was edited. Thank you!

Comment: @LeonardoAugustoCorintaTrint, you iterate over `name_db_data` array and add value to each array. Remove this loop and invoke `array_aux2.add` once for `avg` name.

Comment: @MichałZiober Yes, because I get the correspondent value of Database through `rs.getDouble(name_db_data[count4])`. If I stop on first loop (just add on `avg` name), all objects will be replaced too. I tested it and result is in post.